# Under what conditions is Graph($f$) compact?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C \subseteq R^m$ and assume $C$ is compact. Let $f$ be a map defined from C into $R^n$. We are given that $f$ is continuous. I know that a compact subset is compact under a continuous map. Is this fact enough to show that $Graph(f)$ := {$(x, f(x)) : x \in C$} is compact? Or am I missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of $f$ is a closed subset of $C\times f[C]$, which is a compact set, so yes, the graph of $f$ is compact.